# Verb agreement with percentages

Tags: verb-agreement, percentages

Recently I've come across this sentence in *Keynote Advanced*:

> Over 50 per cent of our materials *come / comes* from local suppliers.

The answer provided in the teacher's book is *comes*. I've checked several grammar textbooks and all of them say that it should be *come*. For example, here is an excerpt from *Advanced Grammar in Use* by Martin Hewgings:

> When the first noun in a complex subject is a percentage or a fraction the verb agrees with the nouns closest to the verb. E.g. About 50% of the houses *need* major repairs.

I'm inclined to think that *comes* in the answer key is a typo, but maybe I'm missing something. Could you please advise?

Comment: The book is wrong. "Per cent" belongs with the number-transparent nouns; the kind where the verb agrees not with the head but with the complement of the preposition "of", Here, the comp is the plural NP "our materials", so it follows that the verb should be the plural form "come". Note that where the head is a collective noun, singular agreement can be overriden: "One percent of the electorate was/were unaware of the issue".

Comment: Does the student book or the teacher book give an explanation of the relevant rule?

Comment: 'Material/s' is a noun with complex count / noncount (see [Wiktionary](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/material)) behaviour, but plural agreement with the plural form is standard (though 'three materials were ...' sounds rather unnatural).

Answer (score 2):

> *Over 50 per cent of our materials come / comes from local suppliers.*

Your inclination is well-founded.

The noun "percent" (or "per cent") belongs with the number-transparent nouns: the kind where the verb agrees not with the head noun but with the noun that is complement of the preposition "of".

Here, the complement is the plural NP "our materials", so it follows that the verb should be the plural form "come".

Note that where the complement of "of" is a collective noun, singular agreement can be overriden: *One percent of the electorate was/were unaware of the issue*.